# I need to change Gamma to .8 on startup

Tags: scripts

I added the command `sudo xgamma -gamma .8` to `rc.local` in order to change the gamma on startup but its not changing it:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sudo xgamma -gamma .8
exit 0
```

Please someone give tell me a method how to change gamma on start up?

Answer (score 1):

As it has been stated already `sudo` it's not needed (neither to run commands in `rc.local` in general, nor for running `xgamma` specifically) but the problem here it's `xgamma` requires (of course) the X server to be running, but `rc.local` it's executed (as it's stated within `rc.local`'s comments) at the end of each multiuser runlevel, which is way before the X server is started.

To run the command right after the X server has been started create a script named `.xinitrc` in `~` (`touch ~/.xinitrc`), mark it as executable with `chmod +x ~/.xinitrc` and put the command there:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

xgamma -gamma .8
exit 0
```

Comment: i understand that rc.local runs before x-server starts.but i dont understand where to save the script file and what is meant by "~" where is it located ?

Comment: @ZiaURahman `~` is a shorthand which expands to your home directory path, so the full path of the script would be something like `/home/yourusername/.xinitrc`. In any case, just place it into your home path (even using `nautilus` if you prefer)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding a startup entry in *Startup Application Preferences*.

Open *Startup Application Preferences* and click **Add**.

In the *Name* enter `Gamma` or whatever you like.

In the *Command* field enter `/usr/bin/xgamma -gamma X.X`

Where `X.X` is the value you want gamma to be set to.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` is not needed in rc.local. As well, I belive `exit 0` should remain on its own line. I recommend you change to:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

xgamma -gamma 0.8

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me for gnome V42.4

Create a `.desktop` file (launcher). Put it in `~/.config/autostart` then you'll see that it's already included in your startup programs.

The contents of the file should be:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Name=GammaConfig  
Icon=none  
Type=Application  
Exec=xgamma -gamma 1.3 (you can modify the 1.3 value with your preferences)  
Terminal=false
```